# How can I lift the latch of the battery compartment in this smoke alarm detector?

Tags: smoke-detectors, battery

First of all, I'm a bit embarrassed I cannot figure this out myself.
I have looked up Youtube videos, Google searched but I didn't find any exact video.

Plus I have tried pressing it hard, lifting but it seems very hard - just hurts my thumb.
I don't want to call an electrician or tell my landlord but I can't sleep with this chirp going on as well. Can anyone help?

[image: t]

Comment: There's a possibility of a pin that keeps the battery hatch "locked". (It's a landlord thing where they don't want tenants tampering.)

Comment: Where can that pin be?

Comment: Also, looking at the manual if there was a pin - I wouldn't have been able to turn and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Push the tab toward the arrow and then lift it up. Good luck

Comment: How can I tell the model number of this?  
Btw, I tried pushing the tab but it just doesn't move or shift.

Comment: Does it also mean the whole alarm should have been replaced by 2014?

Comment: yes, they are good for 10 years and then need to be replaced. It's about the sensor life span. Just replace it

Answer (score 1):

## You might want to check a calander!

[image]

contact your municipal authprity for instructions on how to correctly dispose of radioactive spmoke alarms.

Answer (score 0):

Push tab in the other direction, then lift

Comment: It worked. Cool.